# MapReduce or Normal Queries? (Several emits per Map)

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mapreduce

I have some different Map/Reduces functions that I use in my project. But one is a lot different than the others since it requires a loop in the map functionality. And for each count in the loop, I send an emit.

What I have is this scenario (in the user collection):

```
 "channels" : [
        "Channel 1",
        "Channel 2",
    ],
```

What I want to do is to count how many users each channel has. So for that I could use `db.users.find({channels: "Channel 1"}).count()` but unfortunately channels are dynamic which means I don't know all the possible channel names and it may well change in the future.

So I thought that a Map/Reduce job would sit just perfect. But the problem is that the first  Reduce job I wrote calculated wrong. And the other where I used a query for each emit, would  come to take forever (more than 3 hours before the ssh session shut down).

So now I'm stuck and I need help, preferably I would want to have a Map/Reduce job since it's more nice than a bunch of queries which is kind of slow to run in real time.

This is the latest `Map` and `Reduce` functions I wrote:

```
var map = function() {
    if(this.channels) {
            for(var i = 0, imax = this.channels.length; i<imax; i++) {
            emit(this.channels[i], 1);
        }   
    }
}

var reduce = function (key, values) {
    var result = 0;

    values.forEach(function (value) {
        // had this before: result += 1;
        result = db.users.find({'channels' : key}).count();
    });

    return result;
}
```

I knew that the reduce function was horrific but I just tried the best I could think of. I think my logic may seem wrong but I can't find a good solution. Now I'm thinking of just doing a bunch of queries on every page load, but it will be slow as hell.

Please help! :)

Comment: All I can think of that would work for sure is creating a new collection with Map Reduce, and then for each channel calculate the right amount of users that have it. But I will continue to lab with trying to get a working Map/Reduce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your scenario the reduce function should look like this:

```
var reduce = function (key, values) {
    var result = 0;

    values.forEach(function (value) {
        result += value;
    });

    return result;
}
```

Let me know if it is still not working and if it does please give an example of input and (incorrect) output.

Comment: Running it now, it usually takes approx.. 2 min because of the collection size.

Comment: It calculates wrong, I think I've event tested with your example before. Your reduce example produces this result (as an example): `{ "_id" : "Example", "value" : 557325 } `. But when I uses this: `db.users.find({channels: "Example"}).count() ` I get `557286 `. Not such a big difference, but still a difference. I frankly don't understand why. Still up voted your answer since it was damn good.

Comment: It means that you have errors in DB, i.e. there are users which have multiple `"Example"` entries in `channels` list. Trying firing `emit` in map function only for unique keys (omit duplicates).

Comment: Ok, thanks for your answer. I've accepted it now. I don't think those multiple channels make such a big deal anyway. :)

Answer (score 1):

MR is sometimes a bit slow. So you might want to check out the new aggregation framework coming with 2.2 (which i think is s currently in release phase).

See: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/aggregation/

Additionally you might need to speed up the queries via using proper indices. Or adding a user count to the channels and increasing/decreasing when the user joining/leaving a channel. Depends on your app's use case of course.

Comment: Thanks, but it'll be fine with Map/Reduce for this instance. I'll just work on this project 'till friday. But nice link, I will for sure read about the new aggregation framework.